# Looking for way to exit system or stop code

Tags: java

The current code below is causing the error to trip when out of bounds input is put in, and then print the error to the screen which is what I want. 
Yet the issue is that after the code trips it's still printing the answer instead of then just stopping.
I tried to put a system exit statement in the if code under the message, but then the IDE alerts me that the else needs an "if" for some reason.
Is there a way to stop all functions after the code prints to the screen

```
    public Driver(double[] test) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        scoreArray = new double[test.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
        {
            if (test[i] < 0 || test[i] > 100)
                System.err.println("Test scores must have a value less than 100 and greater than 0.");
               // throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test scores must have a value less than 100 and greater than 0.");
            else
                scoreArray[i] = test[i];
        }
    }
```

Full code 
The IDE i use is netbeans

```
package driver;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat; 


public class Driver
{
    private double[] scoreArray;

    public Driver(double[] test) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        scoreArray = new double[test.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
        {
            if (test[i] < 0 || test[i] > 100)
                System.err.println("Test scores must have a value less than 100 and greater than 0.");
               // throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test scores must have a value less than 100 and greater than 0.");
            else
                scoreArray[i] = test[i];
        }
    }

    public double getAverage()
    {
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++)
            total += scoreArray[i];

        return (total / scoreArray.length);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  
        int score = 0;
       // int scores = 0;

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter number of test scores:");
        score = userInput.nextInt();

        double[] scoreArray = new double[score];

        for (int i = 0; i <= score - 1; i++)
        {    
            System.out.print("Enter test score " + (i + 1)+ ":");
            //scoreArray[scores] = userInput.nextDouble();  
            scoreArray[i] = userInput.nextDouble();
        }
        DecimalFormat ft = new DecimalFormat("####");
        ft = new DecimalFormat("0.0"); 
        Driver testScore  = new Driver(scoreArray);
        //System.out.println(driver.getAverage);
        System.out.println(ft.format(testScore.getAverage()));
    }
}
```

Comment: `break` or `return` would work - but I kind of like the use of the exception

Comment: If you want to put two statements in an `if`, you need to put braces `{}` around them. Common wisdom is to always use braces with `if` statements.

Comment: thanks guys, added the brackets and it let me input my code. did not realize something so simple could make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put two statements in an `if`, you need to put braces `{}` around them. Common wisdom is to always use braces with `if` statements. That's why the compiler told you it was an error when you tried to add another statement between the `if` and the `else`.

Like this:

```
if (test[i] < 0 || test[i] > 100) {
    System.err.println("Test scores must have a value less than 100 and greater than 0.");
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test scores must have a value less than 100 and greater than 0.");
} else { 
    scoreArray[i] = test[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. i left out the throw new, but instead put the brackets like you said and instead added the System.exit(0); under the print out line and it fixed it